# is there a way to move folder to trash using cmd.exe or powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

- is there a way to move a folder to trash using cmd.exe? (Windows Vista)
  (that is, the behavior should be identical to user moved the folder to trash from GUI)
- is there a way to do it using PowerShell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For PowerShell, see: [How do I move a file to the Recycle Bin using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502002/how-do-i-move-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin-using-powershell)

For CMD, see: [CMD Command to delete files and put them into Recycle Bin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646425/cmd-command-to-delete-files-and-put-them-into-recycle-bin)